# Restartarting GameViewController/GameScene

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, skscene

Once my game is complete, I am running  `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToGameOver", sender: nil)` in my GameViewController, which holds my GameScene through

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.showsFPS = false
    skView.showsNodeCount = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Then, in my GameOverViewController when the user clicks my playAgainButton it runs `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`

But then it goes back to my GameViewController/GameScene which doesn't reload and is in the same state which it was left in... How can I "reinitialize" or re-present the GameScene through my ViewController's SKView?

This sort of problem is also in my store, when a user clicks a side arrow it moves "modally" to a different ViewController and they buy  my ingame currency, but when they click my back arrow and I run `self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` The elements such as my UILabel linked with an IBOutlet, is not updating the new amount of in-game currency... If I'm not wrong, then it's because the viewcontroller/scene isn't reloading. How would I fix both of these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save user state via Core Data or using `NSUserDefaults` for lightweight data. When `GameScene` is initialized, `GameScene` can load state from the local store. This would also mean that you would need to write to the local store when when deallocating `GameScene`. In addition, this would also solve the ingame currency issue. Simply update your Core Data model when the user has added credits.

An alternative to this would be using the delegate pattern. Define a `protocol` which `GameScene` conforms to within `GameOverViewController`. `GameScene` would not be deallocated when presenting `GameOverViewController` because `GameOverViewController` would have a reference to `GameScene`. Therefore, that instance of `GameScene` would have a reference held by `GameOverViewController` (to add credits, update labels, ect.). For an example of the delegate pattern, check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31232866/how-to-redraw-my-view-in-swift/31234141#31234141)

I would recommend going with the first approach as using persistence will save user state between launches.

Comment: Thank you very much @BenJammin but unfortunately I do not have that much knowledge about Core Data, could you give me any pointers on how to use it? I've used NSUserDefaults a lot but they don't always update in time...

Comment: Core data is a large part of iOS development. There are many moving parts and use cases; As such, I would recommend a few simple Raywenderlich.com tutorials and apples core data guide. Once you understand the framework and the managed object model you can tailor the framework to your specific needs. I don't know what type of data you need saved.

Comment: I found a great tutorial on raywenderlich.com! Thank you very much!

Comment: Use SQLite, is very easy with this Framework https://github.com/rondinellimorais/HelperLibrary

Comment: In my game, when user touch button play again, I simply clean all nodes e restore all var to default values while GameScene continues running. GameOverView, PauseView or any view is element of storyboard 'ContainerView' that is show/hide